# Server Infrastructure, file upload project

Tags: python, linux, django, ftp, freebsd

I am planning to create a file upload website where users register as members and then upload files through both a file upload form and ftp account (each file can be up to 10gb). 
For each file uploaded the member gets provided with a link which he can share with other users. Unfortunately I am just an average Django coder/linux user and have not worked on any similar project before.

Problem 1

The storage space used will potentially quickly grow to 1000s of TB's, how do I optimise the server and its storage for this? Should I use a Cloud-service or which type of Hosting would be most suitable? How would you setup the Infrastructure to make this run smoothly?

I was planning to run Freebsd as OS and Django/Python for the Development ...

Appreciate your input and all ideas!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you describe, I would start with a cloud service and see how the actual usage turns out. That might be the cheapest and most scalable version.

For setting things up, you have several options (surprise! `:-)` ). AFAIK, Amazon has some preconfigured images that might take you a long way. Since you're doing python, you could also look at Google and see how their services play together.

As you described yourself primarily as a coder, I would stay away from puppet, chef, ansible and such. While those are great tools, they add a layer of abstraction to managing actual servers. I might be wrong, of course, and such tools are just the help you need in order to set things up.

For many admin-tools, there are ready-to-use modules or templates that might help you achieve your goal.

As a simple battle-plan suggestion:

1. look at cloud-providers to determine which one suites you well.
2. look at tools to interact with the cloud-provider you are thinking about using.
3. try to find user-groups for the cloud-provider/admin tool you chose to learn more about them or get help from other people.